# How to add points/lines/polygons to empty layer in Carto Builder?

Tags: carto

I created an empty map in Carto Builder.  It contained an empty layer.  When I selected that layer in the sidebar, a toolbar for adding points/lines/polygons appeared in the lower left of the map layer.  I used that to add a point.  So far so good.

Then I wanted to add a line.  So I added an empty layer to my map, and selected it in the sidebar.  But the toolbar for adding points/lines/polygons did not appear in the lower left of the map layer.

How do I add a point/line/polygon to a new empty layer in Builder?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/11053) of BUILDER. In order to fix this, you would need to refresh the webpage. Then the options for adding geometries to the second layer should appear on the map.